# Custom icon in PrimeFaces button doesn't work

Tags: primefaces

I'm trying to put an image/icon inside a button in Primefaces, problem is the image doesn't show. I'd used FireBug and look like the path is correct. Is there any problem or restrictions using Custom icons?

XHTML code:

```xml
<p:button type="button" value="Limpiar" icon="img-button-prismaticos" onclick="limpiar  ();return false;"  />
```

CSS Code:

```css
.ui-state-default .img-button-prismaticos {
    background-image: url('/dinarep/faces/javax.faces.resource/prismaticos-icono-9281-48.png?ln=images') !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fix the problem. It's related with the size of the span where imagen are located on the button. Is only 16x16!. I fix channging the size and margins of the span in CSS. I  use important! to hack the CSS because i don't want to overwrite the default Primefaces Styles. And I want my margins has more priority.

```
.img-button-nube {
    background-image: url('/dinarep/faces/javax.faces.resource/nubes-icono.png?ln=images') !important;
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
    left: 0 !important;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

and in the XHTML (no changes):

```
<p:button type="button" icon="img-button-nube" onclick="nubes();return false;"  />
```

It's work for me...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this without .ui-state-default

.img-button-prismaticos {
    background-image: url('/dinarep/faces/javax.faces.resource/prismaticos-icono-9281-48.png?ln=images') !important;
}

best
vj

Comment: I try with .ui-state-default and without this and don`t work...I fix the problem...I'll answer my cuestion with the solution